# Delete row in excel while exporting using php

Tags: php

I have a php file where i export data from database to excel using

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=cel.xls");
```

Now, i want to delete the first row of the file before it is exported. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: This sample of code is supposed to give us information about your problem ? Are you creating this Excel file ? You are using a library ? Where are the data ?

Comment: the file amounts to 300 lines of codes and also it is a part of my big website so even if i give u the file u pretty much wont be able to get the full idea behind it. here is the page http://pastie.org/9885726 . Line #80 should be deleted but if i comment it then there are two field that depend on this line. Any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you can try this sample code

```
if(isset($_POST['Upload'])) {

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "files/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
        $file_target="files/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $data->read($file_target);  
    // $x = 2 indicates second row of the excel sheet //
for($x = 2;$x<=count($data->sheets[0]["cells"]); $x++) { 
    $first_cell = $data->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][1];
    $second_cell = $data->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][2];
    $third_cell = $data->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][3];
    }
  }
}
```